# Not able to retrieve data from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting the paypal payment information in a table "payments". The structure of the table is as below:

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
 `payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `txn_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `payment_gross` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `currency_code` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `payment_status` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `payer_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`payment_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The payment is successfully saved. I want to retrieve the information from same table on txn_id received from paypal upon the redirection to "success.php" page . The code i am using is as below:

```
include 'config/database.php';
include 'DBController.php';
file_put_contents("log.txt", print_r($_POST, true));
//Get payment information from PayPal 
//$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
//$txn_id= isset($_GET['tx']) ? $_GET['tx'] : '';
//$payment_gross = isset($_GET['amt']) ? $_GET['amt'] : '';
//$currency_code = isset($_GET['cc']) ? $_GET['cc'] : '';
//$payment_status = isset($_GET['st']) ? $_GET['st'] : '';
//$txn_id = $_GET['tx'];
//$payment_gross = $_GET['amt'];
//$currency_code = $_GET['cc'];
//$payment_status = $_GET['st'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$currency_code = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
file_put_contents("log1.txt", print_r($txn_id, true));
if(!empty($txn_id))
{
    $db = new DBController();
    //Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
    $param_type="s";

    $param_value_array = array($txn_id);

    $paymentResult = $db->runQuery1("SELECT payment_id FROM payments1 WHERE txn_id = ?",$param_type,$param_value_array);

    if(!$paymentResult== 0)
```

0 rows are returned.

Comment: Note that money is rarely FLOAT; it's why DECIMAL was invented

Comment: but if i just select payment id only then also i am not able to retrieve anything. @ strawberry

Comment: Looks like something's wrong with your database design if id and status fields are 255 long strings...

Comment: is your table  payments1 or payments

Comment: @james can u ellaborate plz

Comment: payments. payments1 was just replicated to troubleshoot. nonetheless it worked

Comment: I thought I was clear already. Is your status values really 255 characters long? Then you should have another table to store them and use surrogate keys.

Comment: i have changed the varchar to 25 for txn_id and payment status fields. still facing the same problem

Comment: You need to debug this yourself. Check your database class and echo out the sql query, make sure that the values correspond to what you want and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps we need to know a bit more about runQuery1()